# User-defined keys within a Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like users to be able to define which keys they'd like to use during a pygame session. I include a short example below where I'd like to change the current working event_handler() function so that it can utilise a user-defined key to quit during the loop:

A more advanced python user might also be able to advise me as to how the user could choose a function key or the up/down/left/right arrows of the keyboard too?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
size = display_width, display_height = 200,100
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((400,200))

userQuitKey = "K_"+"q"
print(userQuitKey)

def event_handler():      
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_q):
        #if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == userQuitKey):
            pygame.quit()
            quit()   

for r in range(210,255):
    for g in range(210,255):
        for b in range(210,255):
            event_handler()
            DS.fill((r,g,b))
            pygame.display.update()
print("Loops have ended!")
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: One of the answers from your link suggests that this is done:
input_map = {'move right': pygame.K_d, 'move left': pygame.K_a}
I don't understand why my proposed solution of userQuitKey = "K_"+"q" wouldn't essentially do the same thing.

Comment: `"K_"+"q"` is a string, but you need the pygame constant `K_q` which is actually an int (`113`). If you want to use a string to get the value of `K_q`, you can use the `getattr` function: `userQuitKey = getattr(pygame, "K_"+"q")`.

Comment: Thanks Skrx, this last comment of yours, together with the link you posted above have clarified everything!

Comment: Here's a list of the key constants: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Comment: where did you get "K_q which is actually an int (113)" ?

Comment: I just printed it.